# Doctrine MongoDB ODM Authentication, possible?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm

Is there a way to use MongoDB authentication in Doctrine MongoDB ODM?
equivilant to db.auth(username,password) in shell

Answer (score 4):

The most robust method is to specify your username and password in the connection URI (e.g. `mongodb://username:password@localhost`), as that will allow the driver to re-authenticate if a connection is dropped and it needs to reconnect. You can also use [MongoDB::authenticate()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.authenticate.php) if you need to authenticate against various DB's in a single connection, but you will have to manually re-authenticate if the connection is dropped. See the [connection documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.php) for more examples.